# MySQL select where one of two columns matches and order by column from another table

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql statement where I select all friends for a user.

```
SELECT * 
FROM friends 
WHERE (user1 = FRIEND_ID_HERE AND confirmed = 1) 
   OR (user2 = FRIEND_ID_HERE AND confirmed = 1);
```

The problem is that the friend can be either `user1` or `user2` in the `friends table` so I dont really know how to join the `members table` and sort them by `last_online` when I dont know which column contains the friend.

How can I do this most efficiently? Thanks!

**table members**

```
user_id | username | last_online
--------------------------------
      1 |    user1 | 1502296162
      2 |    user2 | 1502296161
      3 |    user3 | 1502296160
      4 |    user3 | 1502296159
```

**table friends**

```
 id | user1 | user2 | confirmed
-------------------------------
  1 |     1 |     2 | 1502296162
  2 |     3 |     1 | 1502296161
  3 |     2 |     4 | 1502296160
```

Comment: Do two queries, one that joins `user1` and another that joins `user2`. Combine them with `UNION`, and order that result.

Comment: post `members` table schema

Comment: "most efficiently" - probably with a UNION ALL statement.

Comment: updated with table schema, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM members JOIN (
  SELECT user2 AS id FROM friends WHERE (user1 = FRIEND_ID_HERE AND confirmed = 1)
  UNION
  SELECT user1 AS id FROM friends WHERE (user2 = FRIEND_ID_HERE AND confirmed = 1)
) f ON memebers.id = f.id
ORDER BY last_online;
```

Comment: When `user1 = FRIEND_ID_HERE` you want to `SELECT user2`. Otherwise you will only get `FRIEND_ID_HERE` in your UNION subquery.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel friend id might be in `user1` or  `user2`

Comment: @Ali check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca4ebd/7) If you don't get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE confirmed=1 AND friend_id_here IN (user1,user2)
```